# How to implement property level access control in Keycloak

Tags: authorization, openid-connect, keycloak, acl, access-control

I need the ability to restrict the mutation of individual properties on a resource object.

Ex: John is allowed to update Foo.bar and Foo.baz, but Jane is only allowed to update Foo.bar

Is there any way to accomplish this in Keycloak? Perhaps with a javascript policy enforcer that checks the payload of a PUT against a list of fine grained scopes (foo:bar:update, foo:baz:update) or something along those lines?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure of your use case,  you can check permissions granted by Keycloak for a authenticated user using `AuthorizationContext.hasResourcePermission("Foo.bar").`

You can check the authz [quickstarts](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/master/app-authz-springboot/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quickstart/springboot/security/Identity.java) to know how to get `AuthorizationContext`

https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/blob/master/app-authz-springboot/src/main/java/org/keycloak/quickstart/springboot/security/Identity.java

Answer (score -2):

In an architectural PoV, the policy enforcement - *authorization* - itself should be performed by an *API gateway*. The gateway would compare incoming request against a predefined set of policies and authorize the request or not.

In Keycloak you can use a combination of *Groups* and *Roles*. A Group can have a defined Role which gets applied on all members of the Group. Therefore you create a user being a member of multiple Groups resulting in having multiple roles. A nice bonus is ability to list users based on their group membership.

PS: Personally, I don't have experience with *Scopes* but they should work too.

---

Example:

You create groups `Bar` having role `BAR` and `Baz` having role `BAZ`. Then you assign user John to both `Bar` & `Baz` and Jane to `Bar` only. On the API gateway you check PUT request's properties against array of roles incoming from the `Authorization` header.